# Uncheck "Send an email invitation" for SharePoint onlie by default

Tags: sharepoint-online

It's SharePoint online. Is there a way to uncheck "Send an email invitation" for all sites? By default this is on.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SharePoint online, there is no method to disable “send an email invitation” when providing user permission. The only method is to uncheck “send an email invitation” when providing user permission.

I would recommend you submit a feedback about this issue via the below link for your convenience, thanks.

https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I am writing powershell script to add bunch of AD groups to SharePoint group and I dont want to trigger email notifications. Is there a way to suppress it?